# Matching a part of sentence starting with "the" or "a" and ending with a number

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that identifies the following: "[the or a] [text] [number]"

For example, In the following string:

```
"The foo or the bar 100. A large machine 200."
```

I need a regular expression that separately matches

```
"the bar 100"
"A large machine 200"
```

without matching

```
"the foo or the bar 100"
```

Any suggestions?

I am implementing regex with C#.

Comment: first of all, it doesnt look like you even tried to solve ur question, show us the code you made for this.

Comment: (?i)(a|the) (.*?) (\d+)(\W) ... The problem with this is that it will identify "the foo or the bar 100".

Comment: hmm would you like to solve ur problem without regex?

Comment: I think I could programmatically do this by parsing with string functions in c#. However, I would rather use a regular expression if it is possible.

Comment: Can the text be multiple words? If no and the text is one word only, then you can change &quot;(. *?)&quot; to &quot; [a-zA-Z] &quot; (be aware that the string contains spaces before [ and after ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work... There maybe a less verbose way though

```
\bthe\b(?:(?!\bthe\b).)*?\d+|\ba\b(?:(?!\ba\b).)*?\d+
```

**Explanation**

Given the first part `\bthe\b(?:(?!\bthe\b).)*?\d+`

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary
- `the` matches the characters `the` literally
- `\b` assert position at a word boundary

Non-capturing group `(?:(?!\bthe\b).)*?`

- `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Negative Lookahead `(?!\bthe\b)` *Assert that the Regex below does not match*

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary
- `the` matches the characters `the` literally
- `\b` assert position at a word boundary

Continuing with

- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**Example**

```
var pattern = @"\bthe\b(?:(?!\bthe\b).)*?\d+|\ba\b(?:(?!\ba\b).)*?\d+";
var input = "The foo or the bar 100. A large machine 200. The transformer 100 and a bridge 200. GufftheGuff guffAguff is not matching 100";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
"the bar 100"
"A large machine 200"
"The transformer 100"
"a bridge 200"
```

---

[Here is a demo for your amusement](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iz4iXB)

[You can play with it a bit more here](https://regex101.com/r/eybIcC/2)

Comment: "\bthe\b(?:(?!\b(the|a)\b).)*?\d+|\ba\b(?:(?!\b(a|the)\b).)*?\d+"

Comment: I tweaked your regex string just a little with (?!\b(the|a)\b).)*? and it seems to work! Thanks for your help

Comment: @AndrewUmlauf glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. All you needed was a negative look ahead.

Here's how your regex would be:

```
(?i)((?!\ba\b.*?\ba\b)\ba\b.+?\d+)|((?!\bthe\b.*?\bthe\b)\bthe\b.+?\d+)
```

Basically `\b` meta characters are there to match `the` and `a` as words, rather than as part of words. So if you strip them out, you get:

```
(?i)((?!the.+?the)the.+?\d+)|((?!a.+?a)a.+?\d+)
```

Let's look at one of them to understand what it does:

```
((?!the.+?the)the.+?\d+)
 ^ -- Negative lookahead to ensure that the matched group doesn't have the word "the" twice
              ^ -- There is a word "the"
                ^ -- Followed by any characters
                    ^ -- Followed by some digits
```

The same applied for other part of regex.

You can try out various combinations here: https://regex101.com/r/ZNMg7E/3

Comment: Very Helpful. This is close! However, it is still not working on the phrase "The transformer and a bridge 200" I would like to only match "a bridge 200" in this phrase

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Pattern** `or\s(?<w1>[\w\s]+).\s(?<w2>[\w\s]+).`
*Code*

```
string bs = "The foo or the bar 100. A large machine 200.";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"or\s(?<w1>[\w\s]+).\s(?<w2>[\w\s]+).");
        Match match = regex.Match(bs);
        if (match.Success)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["w1"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["w2"].Value);
        }
        // Outputs "the bar 100" and "A large machine 200"
```

**This is not regex but you can still use it if you cant use regex pattern**

```
string bs = "The foo or the bar 100. A large machine 200.";
        string[] dotspl = bs.Split(new string[]{". "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string pt1 = dotspl[0].Split(new string[]{" or "}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        string pt2 = dotspl[1];
        Console.WriteLine(pt1 + " and " + pt2);
```

Comment: nvm i m hunting for regex patterns

Comment: Here is another sample: The transformer 100 and a bridge 200" should match "the transformer 100" and "a bridge 200". However. "The transformer and a bridge 200" should only match "a bridge 200"  ...  I tried to figure out how i could use look ahead / look behind, but I was struggling.

Comment: ya those expressions are very difficult